# JSON Parse for Highcharts

Tags: javascript, json, highcharts

I've viewed a ton of examples.  Yet, I'm still stuck on this.  How do I parse this JSON response to work with my Highstock Highchart?

```
[{"averageprice":"18.7","date":"2000-01-01"},{"averageprice":"41.73","date":"2000-01-02"},{"averageprice":"34.27","date":"2000-01-03"},{"averageprice":"30.06","date":"2000-01-04"}]
```

Here is my chart so far...

```
    $.getJSON('http://example.com/dailyaverages.json', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'ppcontent'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 0
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Trade Prices'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series : [{
            data : data
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Most modern browsers support the `JSON.parse()` method, which does exactly what its name suggests it does.

Answer (score 0):

Axis and data expect array. Please try:

```
$.getJSON('http://example.com/dailyaverages.json', function(data) {
    // Create the chart
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
        chart : {
            renderTo : 'ppcontent'
        },

        rangeSelector : {
            selected : 0
        },

        title : {
            text : 'Trade Prices'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },
        series : [{
            name: "Trade Prices",
            data : function() {
                  var dataArr = [];
                  dataObj.forEach(function(d) {
                    dataArr.push(parseInt(d.averageprice, 10));
                  });
                  return dataArr;
              }() 
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank Munish.  This looks close, but it's returning the error. "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o".  And my console points to this line:  var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: I think the second parameter to getJSON function is the data to be sent to the server. If there is nothing to be sent, then you can pass null. So, your first line would look like: `$.getJSON('http://example.com/dailyaverages.json', null, function(data) {`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me.  Had to convert date to UNIX format:

```
function addPriceChart(chartcontainerID, chartTitle, dataURL) {
          $.getJSON(dataURL, function (jsonresult) {

            window.chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
              chart: {
                renderTo: chartcontainerID
              },

              rangeSelector: {
                selected: 1
              },

              title: {
                text: chartTitle
              },

              credits: {
                enabled: false
              },

              series: [{
                name: 'Price1',
                data: function () {
                  var dataArr = [];
                  jsonresult.forEach(function (row) {
                    var dateParts = row.date.split('-');
                    var date = new Date(dateParts[0], (dateParts[1] - 1), dateParts[2]);
                    var data = [date.getTime(), parseFloat(row.averageprice)];
                    dataArr.push(data);
                  });
                  return dataArr;
                }(),
                tooltip: {
                  valueDecimals: 2
                }
              }]
            });
          });
    } // END addPriceChart Function


    addPriceChart('ppcontent', 'Prices, 'http://mysite.com/data.json');
```